# Adding extra zeros to floating number division - Python

Tags: python, precision

Hey I have this function and I want the returned result to have extra zeros

for example if I call it with base_percentage(6, 3)

I would like to get 0.800 but now am getting 0.8

```
def base_percentage(self, hits, offbase, atbats):
    return float(hits+offbase)/float(atbats)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add extra zeros to a float since 0.8 = 0.800. What you can do however is add extra zeros when you print the float like so:

```
f = 0.8
print("{:.3f}".format(f))
>>> 0.800
```

The above says to print `f` to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use C-like `%` formats:

```
>>> print("%6.3f" % (1.1))
 1.100
>>> print("%6.3f" % (0.8))
 0.800
```